# GNU Screen 'ctrl+a w' doesn't show any information

Tags: gnu-screen

I am using GNU [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) and used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> to instantiate multiple windows.  However, when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>w</kbd> to list the windows at the bottom of the screen, nothing happens.  (I am logged into a Linux cluster.  When running screen directly on my Macbook, this feature works fine.)

Why doesn't <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>w</kbd> do anything, as the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Default-Key-Bindings.html#Default-Key-Bindings) suggests it should?

Edit to add: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd> does not give any output, either.

Comment: Absolutely nothing wrong with asking here, but you may find an answer more quickly in the future by using https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gnu-screen . You can search there for an answer to this issue, but please don't double-post on both sites.

Comment: Does `control-a ?` list the current bindings and show w is bound to something other than `windows`?

Comment: `ctrl+a ?` does list the current bindings, including:
`windows     ^W w `
`time        ^T t `